# How to display document directory folders files in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone programming. I have created some files inside the document directory folder, but now I want to display those files in table view. How do I this? Can anyone help, please?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to display the names of files?

Answer (score 1):

First You have to Create array of Items who saved in Document directory Folder you just impliment bellow method and code:-

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

    NSFileManager *fM = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *fileList = [[fM directoryContentsAtPath:documentsDirectory] retain];
    directoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSString *file in fileList) {
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
        BOOL isDir = NO;
        [fM fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:(&isDir)];
        if(isDir) {
            [directoryList addObject:file];
        }
    }
```

after creating array of document directroy you can count and display each items in your TableView

Comment: Hi i want to display this in thumnails

Comment: I have taken this in array iam able to display this things in tableview.But i want to display in thumbnails.

Comment: you must set ImageVIew with fixed size and give proparty of scal to fit and if you want create like gridView then you can do with Custom cell